# Want to Know which JAR in Hibernate responsible reading cfg.XML file

Tags: hibernate

There are many tags for XML in Hibernate. If I know from where they are coming then I can do experiment on this.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is with a decent IDE.  Most IDE's have "hyperlink" functionality with them.  Try creating a project with the Hibernate JAR's, creating a Hibernate XML file with the XSD or DTD declaration, and then control-clicking (or command-clicking) the DTD or XSD.  It should jump you straight to the definition, which should lead you to the JAR file.